# Access array between controller and view in testing

Tags: symfony

in controller methods I have something like:

```
 public function showAllCustomersAction(Request $request) {
        return $this->render('cus/showAllCustomers.html.twig', $myarray);
 }
```

and in view I can of cource access the array $myarray.

My questin is: how to in test access this array. I do not parse HTML. I want just the array.

```
class CustomerTest extends WebTestCase {

    public function testAllCustomers() {
          $client = static::createClient();
          $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/cus/showAllCustomers');

          // here somehow access the array $myarray
    }

}
```

Thank you in advice :)

Answer (score 1):

you can't, the Crawler will return you a Symfony Response object that are not aware of the data passed by the controller to return this response.

You can of course use the DomCrawler component to search for the content displayed by the array (I guess you use it in your view).

Mickaël

Comment: Thank you Mickaël. Can you give me advice how to test data which controller returns to view? Because in my tests, I do not care about HTML. I am care about data, are data right orderd, right agregated etc.. etc...

Comment: Humm... are theses data treated with Javascript to order data ?

You can use Behat/Selenium to test a front end behavior, or more simple: CasperJS